# My objective is to put message response everytime user enter the same email into the snackbar but what i get is a null

Tags: flutter

ive been getting this error for days now but still cant figure it out. My objective is to put message response everytime user enter the same email into the snackbar but what i get is a null.

This is my signup screen.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:form_field_validator/form_field_validator.dart';
import 'package:formvalid/models/register_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:formvalid/progressHUD.dart';
import 'package:formvalid/screens/login.dart';

class SignupScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignupScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignupScreenState createState() => _SignupScreenState();
}

class RegisterAPI {
  Future<RegisterResponse> register(
      String name, String email, String password) async {
    String url = 'http://api.staging.tarsoft.co/api/register';

    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse('$url'),
        body: {'name': name, 'email': email, 'password': password});
    if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 401) {
      print(response.body);
      // print(response.statusCode);
      return RegisterResponse.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      print(response.body);
      throw Exception('Failed to load data');
    }
  }
}

class _SignupScreenState extends State<SignupScreen> {

  TextEditingController passController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController emailController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController nameController = new TextEditingController();
  
  GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  late RegisterResponse _user;
  bool hidePassword = true;
  bool isApiCallprocess = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _user = new RegisterResponse();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ProgressHUD(
      child: _uibuild(context),
      inAsyncCall: isApiCallprocess,
      opacity: 0.3,
    );
  }

  Widget _uibuild(BuildContext context) {
    final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          key: scaffoldKey,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen()));
            },
          )),
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFffffff),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Form(
          key: formKey,
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, right: 40),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: height * 0.04),
                Text(
                  'Prizes and Suprises',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Color(0xFF363f93)),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Await you !',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Color(0xFF363f93)),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: height * 0.03,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                    controller: nameController,
                    onSaved: (input) => _user.name = input,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Enter your name'),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty ||
                          !RegExp(r'^[a-z A-Z]+$').hasMatch(value)) {
                        return 'Enter correct name';
                      } else {
                        return null;
                      }
                    }),
                SizedBox(height: height * 0.05),
                TextFormField(
                    controller: emailController,
                    onSaved: (input) => _user.email = input,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Enter your email'),
                    validator: MultiValidator([
                      RequiredValidator(errorText: 'Enter your email'),
                      EmailValidator(errorText: 'Not A Valid Email')
                    ])),
                SizedBox(height: height * 0.05),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: passController,
                  onSaved: (input) => _user.password = input,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Enter your password'),
                  validator: MultiValidator([
                    RequiredValidator(errorText: 'Enter your password'),
                    MinLengthValidator(6,
                        errorText: 'Should be at least 6 characters')
                  ]),
                  obscureText: hidePassword,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: height * 0.05),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          final String name = nameController.text;
                          final String email = emailController.text;
                          final String password = passController.text;

                          if (validateAndSave()) {
                            setState(() {
                              isApiCallprocess = true;
                            });
                            RegisterAPI registerAPI = new RegisterAPI();
                            registerAPI
                                .register(name, email, password)
                                .then((value) => {
                                      setState(() {
                                        isApiCallprocess = false;
                                      }),
                                      if (value.token?.isNotEmpty ?? false)
                                        {
                                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                              .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                                  content: Text(
                                                      '${_user.name}')))
                                        }
                                      else
                                        {
                                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                              .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                                  content:
                                                      Text('${_user.message}')))
                                        }
                                    });
                            print(_user.toJson());
                          }
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 100.0),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 35, top: 10),
                            child: Text(
                              'Register',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                          height: 40,
                          width: 120,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                            color: Color(0xFF363f93),
                          ),
                        )),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: height * 0.09,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  bool validateAndSave() {
    final form = formKey.currentState;
    if (form!.validate()) {
      form.save();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}

//ignore: must_be_immutable
class TextInput extends StatelessWidget {
  final String textString;
  TextEditingController textController;
  final bool obscureText;
  TextInput(
      {Key? key,
      required this.textString,
      required this.textController,
      required this.obscureText})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF000000)),
      cursorColor: Color(0xFF9b9b9b),
      controller: textController,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      obscureText: obscureText,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: this.textString,
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xFF9b9b9b),
            fontSize: 15,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my responseregister

```dart
class RegisterResponse{
  String? email;
  String? password;
  String? name;
  String? token;
  String? error;
  String? message;
  String? success;


  RegisterResponse({this.email, this.password, this.name,this.token,this.error,this.message,this.success});

  factory RegisterResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      RegisterResponse(
        name: json['name'], 
        email: json['email'], 
        password: json['password'],
        token: json['token'] == null ? json['token'] : '',
        error: json['error'],
        message: json['email'],
        success: json['Success']
          );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {
      'name': name,
      'email': email,
      'password': password,
    };

    return map;
  }
}
```

[this is in debugger console shows "the email has already been taken"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6O93.png)

[display null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzNGx.png)